# Why do I have an indexerror output?

Tags: python

> A friend sent Alexey a message in encrypted form, but Alexey is confused and does not understand it.
> It is necessary to expand the characters in the message that are in parentheses (), and then delete the brackets themselves.
> Input strings will always be correctly formed with the corresponding ().
> Note that parentheses can be nested inside each other.
> Input format
> At the input, you get a string that guarantees the presence of an opening and closing parenthesis. Row Size
> x: 0<x≤50
> Output format
> Your program should output a string with inverted characters that were in brackets and without these brackets themselves.
> Example 1:
> Input: asd(asd) Output: asddsa
> Example 2:
> Input: foo(bar)asd(asd) Output: foorabasddsa
> Example 3:
> Input: fit((tif)) Output: fittif

My solution but it has error:

```
def reverse_inside_brackets(s):
    if not s:
        return s
    if s[0] == '(':
        
        i = 1
        count = 1
        while count > 0:
            if s[i] == '(':
                count += 1
            elif s[i] == ')':
                count -= 1
            i += 1
        
        inside = s[1:i]
        reversed_inside = reverse_inside_brackets(inside)
        return s[0] + reversed_inside + s[i]
    else:
        return s[0] + reverse_inside_brackets(s[1:])


l = input()
print(reverse_inside_brackets(l))
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 2
      1 l = input()
----> 2 print(reverse_inside_brackets(l))

Cell In[16], line 19, in reverse_inside_brackets(s)
     17     return s[0] + reversed_inside + s[i]
     18 else:
---> 19     return s[0] + reverse_inside_brackets(s[1:])

Cell In[16], line 19, in reverse_inside_brackets(s)
     17     return s[0] + reversed_inside + s[i]
     18 else:
---> 19     return s[0] + reverse_inside_brackets(s[1:])

Cell In[16], line 19, in reverse_inside_brackets(s)
     17     return s[0] + reversed_inside + s[i]
     18 else:
---> 19     return s[0] + reverse_inside_brackets(s[1:])

Cell In[16], line 17, in reverse_inside_brackets(s)
     15     inside = s[1:i]
     16     reversed_inside = reverse_inside_brackets(inside)
---> 17     return s[0] + reversed_inside + s[i]
     18 else:
     19     return s[0] + reverse_inside_brackets(s[1:])

IndexError: string index out of range
```

I do not know where the error is, maybe someone will solve the problem, I will be grateful!!!

Comment: This will happen if `i` is at least `len(s)`, because the last valid index of `s[len(s)-1]`.

Comment: So the problem is with how you're calculating `i`. You shouldn't allow it to get too high. Or you should check if it's too high before trying to append it.

Comment: Do you need to handle input such as: abc(d(ef)) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a stack (implemented using a Python list):

```
def reverse_inside(s):
    stack = [""]
    for c in s:
        if c == "(":
            stack.append("")
        elif c == ")":
            r = stack.pop()[::-1]
            stack[-1] += r
        else:
            stack[-1] += c
    assert len(stack) == 1
    return stack[0]

tests = [
    "asd(asd)",
    "foo(bar)asd(asd)",
    "fit((tif))",
    "(nab)(a(an))"
]

for test in tests:
    print(reverse_inside(test))
```

**Output:**

```
asddsa
foorabasddsa
fittif
banana
```

Comment: Thx for ur answer bro!